# Dúvida/problema com "res.locals" depois da autenticação

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando pegar os dados do usuário autenticado, li algumas coisas e fui tentando, consegui pegar todos os dados do usuário mas não consigo pegar apenas uma informação, como por exemplo o nome do usuário logado.

```
 // Middleware
        app.use((req, res, next) => {
            res.locals.usuario = req.user
            res.locals.success_msg = req.flash("success_msg")
            res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg")
            res.locals.error = req.flash("error")
            res.locals.user = req.user || null;
            next();
        })
```

index.js

```
<h4>Categorias: </h4>
<hr>
{{usuario}}
{{#each categorias}}
   <a href="/categorias/{{slug}}"> <h5>{{nome}}</h5></a>
{{else}}

{{/each}}
```

Ao me autenticar e entrar na pagina informada abaixo, aparece todas as informações do usuário, eu queria apenas pegar o nome por exemplo. Oque posso estar errando?

Comment: Não entendi direito, você quer pegar o nome de uma pessoa no middleware onde é gerado o token?

Comment: A sim, havia esquecido de deixar a solução desse problema, consegui resolver hoje! Vlw ae de qualquer forma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O handlebars ele com as novas atualizações ele "bloqueia" o acesso a informações desse tipo, mas tem como estar solicitando esses dados normalmente, basta estar colocando o seguinte trecho no código

```
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            if (req.user) {
              res.locals.usuarioLogado = req.user.toObject();
            }
            next();
          });
```

Com isso todas as informações do usuário logado podem ser utilizadas.